# A deleted answer is shown in the top spot and still shows as accepted

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, deleted-users

I was doing some research and I ran across [What is the 'cls' variable used in python classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613000/what-is-the-cls-variable-used-in-python-classes).  When I opened the question I was very surprised to see a deleted, accepted, answer showing as the first answer.

[image]

When you look at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4616360/timeline) or [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4616360/revisions) there is no record for deletion but when I asked a couple people with less then 10K rep they were not able to see it.  Was this a bug due to the user being removed or is something else going on here?

Comment: I'm curious if the asker can accept a different answer now.

Comment: there is an deletion event on the question timeline: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4613000/timeline

Comment: @rene That is even more curious.  Good find

Comment: @NathanOliver What is curious? Because I assumed that should have clarified what you found?

Comment: @rene It is curious in that the answer timeline does not show the answer was deleted but the question timeline does.  You would think they would both know the answer was deleted.

Comment: Joncle deleted it and undeleted it. Now it's no longer a mystery :/ ... No more fun, No more, No more.

Comment: [247 instances](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/568063) that all show the same issue.

Comment: This is interesting, the OP is still present http://stackoverflow.com/a/1512266/4099593

Comment: I have a feeling this has come up before and has an explanation - just can't remember what it was though. Might be on MSE prior to the split.

Comment: I bet the user was destroyed as a spammer and had all their answers removed automatically.  Or the like.